# Is there a way to remove all this awful whitespace in MS Project 2013?

Tags: microsoft-project-2013

The whole area in the orange box is totally useless and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. It's wasting a tremendous amount of vertical space.

I can collapse the ribbon, but this wasted space just slides up.

[image: Project 2013 whitespace fail]

**Update**

Screen shot showing the timescale portion of the graph as well. Definitely not stacked three high and fonts are normal size.

I was going to say yes it occurs in all my files, but then I realized I based them all on the same template, so I found another project file of no relation, and also created a "new" file and neither showed the same whitespace issue.

It is clearly related to a peculiarity of my specific file, which is great to know.

[image: Whitespace fail with calendar]

Comment: If it occurs with all files created based upon that template, I'd stop using that template :-)  Glad to have helped and thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because one of the columns in my Gantt chart has a long title and I'd squeezed the column width to be very small. (See the title and width of box in screenshot below). The `Field Settings` dialogue for that column had `Header Text Wrapping` box checked, which was causing the header height to grow, even though the text wasn't visible regardless of height.

[image: Checkbox for header text wrapping]

I fixed it by unchecking this box for all visible columns. Note: I tried to select all the columns at once and unchecking the box, but this didn't take. That may just be a bug in Project.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have increased the height of your header row.  Place your mouse above the first task ID on the left side.  Your mouse should look like a thick black line with arrows pointing up and down.  Press and hold down the mouse button.  Drag up to decrease the height of the header row.

[image]

Comment: Indeed, I can make it even more egregiously taller, but no shorter than what you see in my screenshot. FWIW I did try what you're suggesting first and probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the right side (timescaled portion) of the view?  Does this occur in all project files or just one?    The only way I can reproduce your error is to go to 3 tiers in the timescale and then increase the font size of the timescale text.

And yes, it would have been helpful for you to let us know what you tried.

Comment: Done. This alone was helpful advice as I know it's something I've done to my file and not a problem with Project per se.